# Filtering based on ManyToManyField - Get record if item present in list

Tags: python, django

I wanted to know if there was a way for me to filter based on ManyToManyField field. I know there is a `__in` filter however it seems like this filter requires an id and I dont have an id (I could get the ids but I wanted to know if it was possible without it). 
This is what my model looks like

```
class modelEmployee(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, blank=False, null=True)
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill, blank=True)

class modelJob(models.Model):
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill,blank=True)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False,blank=False,null=True)
```

and this is the model of many to many

```
class modelSkill(models.Model):
    skill_description   = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Now I have a list that looks like this

```
  skillList = [SkillA,SkillB,SkillC...] #Description field
```

Currently its not possible for me to do this

```
modelJob.objects.filter(skills__in=skillList)
```

The reason I cant do the above is because skills__in is expecting a list with id nos of the skills and not some other field of the skills. My question is how do I tell skills__in that the list I am passing in are the `skill_description` of the `modelSkill` and not the ids ?

Update:
If I do this

```
  queryset_list = modelEmployee.objects.filter(skills___skill_description__in=skill_filter)
```

I get the error

```
raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: _skill_description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dig one level deeper, and match the `skill_description` field specifically:

```
modelJob.objects.filter(skills__skill_description__in=skillList)
```

From the Django docs:

> For example, if an Entry has a ManyToManyField called tags, we might want to find entries linked to tags called “music” and “bands” or we might want an entry that contains a tag with a name of “music” and a status of “public”.
>
> To handle both of these situations, Django has a consistent way of processing filter() calls. Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.
>
> That may sound a bit confusing, so hopefully an example will clarify. To select all blogs that contain entries with both “Lennon” in the headline and that were published in 2008 (the same entry satisfying both conditions), we would write:
>
> ```
> Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)
> ```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: It is actually an example for many-to-many. The first sentence from the docs is: “For example, if an entry had a ManyToMany field called tags...”

Comment: Ah ok however it doesnt seem to work for my case - I just updated the post

Comment: Your updated example mentions `modelEmployee`. Where is this defined?

Comment: Its the same as modelJob but I just updated the post

Comment: You have three underscores in your example that causes the error. It should have only two.

Comment: Yes. That was a blunder on my part. Thanks for noticing it